# Read Metadata in layout.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using Nextjs with App-Router.

The title of the page should also be visible on the page itself inside a div.
The div is added inside the root layout.js file.

```js
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <header>{title}</header>
        <main>{children}</main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

The metadata is defined statically for each route.

```js
export const metadata = {
  title: "different title for each page",
};
```

Is there a way to read the metadata?

Comment: So you want to set metadata to each page?

Comment: What do you mean by read the metadata?

Comment: In page.js the title is set via metadata. And in layout.js I need the title to use it as a prop.

Comment: Seems like it's not possible as of now.